# How does Semgrep handle two conflicting Typed Metavariable classes?

Tags: semgrep

Semgrep allows you to [specify types](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/pattern-syntax/#typed-metavariables) in your patterns, but if I happen to have two different classes with the same simple type, but a different fully qualified name, how can I disambiguate between the two when writing a rule where I only want to target one of those types?

I'll explain my question through example. Say you have two different libraries that both have the same class name `Foo`.
In one file of my own code I import one library, and use the Foo class:

```
import lib1.* // has Foo class

f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

In another file of my own code, I import the other library and use it’s Foo class:

```
import lib2.* // has different Foo class

f2 = Foo()
f2.baz()
```

In my Semgrep rule, I want to detect things of type Foo from lib1.

```
pattern: (Foo $F)
```

Since my pattern doesn’t know anything about imports, does it just return results from both files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since your pattern only specifies type `Foo`, Semgrep will return both `f1` and `f2` as matches. If you want to match only one of those, you can specify the fully qualified name of the type you want to match:

```
pattern: (lib1.Foo $F)
```